# Write solution in CPLEX optimization studio to .mst file

Tags: optimization, cplex

In the main-block of a .mod-file, I want to write the solution found to a .mst-file. I know that this can be done in other places via commands like [WriteMIPStart](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/topic/ilog.odms.ide.help/refdotnetopl/html/Overload_ILOG_CPLEX_Cplex_WriteSolution.htm) or [writeSolution](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/topic/ilog.odms.ide.help/refdotnetopl/html/Overload_ILOG_CPLEX_Cplex_WriteSolution.htm) but I am unable to find a corresponding method which can be used in the main block of an OPL-script or a corresponding command in the .ops-file (there again, writeLevel exists, but it adjusts only the level and does not trigger the writing process). Odd enough: addMIPstart seems to work for giving a MIPstart to a model, but I do not want to write the solution "manually".

Can anyone advise me a method to get a mst-file from a solution with a command in the main-block? Or do I need to use the callable library e.g. via Java?

Answer (score 0):

Does the basic "write" command work? See [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cplexzos/v12r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cplex.zos.help%2FFileFormats%2Ftopics%2FInteractiveOptimizer_save.html) for more details. It looks like you can just specify (filename).mst, and CPLEX will automatically determine the format from that extension.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use this command, since I use OPL and not the Interactive Optimizer (to me, these many different levels are actually quite confusing, you have APIs, the Interactive Optimizer, OPL and the callable library). So of course, your answer works, but not in my case, since I want to use OPL.